# turn off the saveGIF display RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to know, how can I turn off the pop up of the .GIF that I have made? I have created and used this code:

```
reswd <- "c:/Data/GIF/"

if(!file.exists(paste0(reswd,"Seasonal.gif"))) { # Check if the file exists

  suppressMessages(saveGIF({

    for (i in 1:dim(tmp_Stack1)[3]) plot(tmp_Stack1[[i]],
                                         main=names(tmp_Stack1)[i],
                                         legend=FALSE,
                                         col = c("green", "blue"),
                                         breaks=c(0,.000000000000000000001,1)
)
     },
    movie.name = paste0(reswd,"Seasonal.gif"), 
    ani.width = 480, ani.height = 400, 
    interval=.5))
  }
```

I have tried with "suppressMessages" but doesn't work.
But at the end when the file is save this is displayed. Thanks to all for the future answers!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem like this. Maybe is a bit mess but I will try to put in order more this new code I had combine XD. I hope someone have new ways to do this as well.

```
setwd("c:/Data/Total_Water_Color/")
for (i in 1:dim(tmp_Stack3)[3]){
  png(filename=paste0(names(tmp_Stack3)[i],".png"), width = 480, height = 400)


  plot(tmp_Stack3[[i]],
       main=names(tmp_Stack3)[i],
       legend=FALSE,
       col = c("green", "blue"),
       breaks=c(0,.000000000000000000001,1))

  dev.off()
}
```

The next code is for create the GIF and dont pop up when is finish.

```
setwd("c:/Data/GIF/")
list.files(path="c:/Data/Total_Water_Color/", pattern = '*.png', full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  image_read() %>% # reads each path file
  image_join() %>% # joins image
  image_animate(fps=1) %>% # animates, can opt for number of loops
  image_write("Total.gif") # write to current dir
```

If someone have a better answer Im open to hear any other better and maybe shorter one option.